# Installing with packer: "sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment"

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, aur

I'm on Arch Linux (4.11.9-1) trying to install a package from AUR using [packer](https://github.com/keenerd/packer).

During installation, after compressing the package, I'm asked for my sudo password which I enter.

Then, installation fails with this error message:

> sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment

What's the reason for this error and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is this line in my sudoers file (check yours with `visudo`):

```
# I can use pacman with sudo and don't have to enter a password
me ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/pacman
```

This line didn't seem to agree with packer; removing it made the installation work.